# Spring SavedRequest aware of X-Forwarded-Prefix

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

When using following architecture using two proxies

```
                    X-Forwarded-Prefix=/a  X-Forwarded-Prefix=/a
 /a/b/auth  +----------+  /b/auth  +----------+  /b/auth +----------+
   +------->|          |+--------->|          |+-------->|          |
            |  HTTPd   |           |   Zuul   |          | Auth     |
   <-------+|          |<---------+|          |<--------+| Service  |
            +----------+           +----------+          +----------+
```

When filter triggers `HttpSessionRequestCache` during auth flow (when user is not authenticated) request is saved without considering `X-Forwarded-Prefix` even when using `server.use-forward-headers=true` (sounds normal because [`RemoteIpValve`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html) does not handle `X-Forwarded-Prefix`).

Thus after that `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` will redirect user on `/b/XXX` instead of `/a/b/XXX`

Could it be a possible issue? Or just my use case is too uncommon and I have to handle myself header `X-Forwarded-Prefix`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed since *Spring 4.3* that provides an alternative to `RemoteIpValve` named [`ForwardedHeaderFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/ForwardedHeaderFilter.html)